# Как получить все Items из TreeList?

Tags: c#

Как получить все Items из TreeList? По аналогий с Combobox - `combobox.Items.Tostring()`. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: 1. `combobox.Items.Tostring()`??
2. WPF? WinForms? ASP .NET?

Comment: @vosxodnik, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: В WinForms!

Comment: если treelist узлы вложенные как в treeview, то пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/478568/196972)