# Где хранятся данные дерева TreeView в Visual Studio и можно ли все дерево сериализировать?

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview

Доброго дня, уважаемые гуру .net

Пытаюсь сделать двухуровневый список на базе `TreeView` в `WinForms`. Через интерфейс дизайнера форм можно редактировать узлы дерева, но как получить к ним доступ программно не смог понять.

Кроме того хотел бы после редактирования в форме приложения весь список узлов сохранить в файл (базу данных). Есть ли у визуальных компонентов и конкретно TreeView встроенная возможность сохранить состояние объекта во внешнее хранилище или какой метод можно применить для этого?

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: А вообще, сериализацией данных должны заниматься сами данные, а не графические элементы.

Comment: _"как получить к ним доступ программно не смог понять."_ -- во время выполнения в цикле взять каждый tree.Nodes и для каждого TreeNode ... см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

`TreeView`, как почти все остальные визуальные компоненты в WinForms - это обертки поверх нативных элементов WinAPI.

Почти все нативные элементы в WinAPI - это окна. Т.е. любая кнопка - это окно.

`TreeView`, в частности, это окно с window class `WC_TREEVIEW`. Любые действия с ним - это не прямая смена какого-то состояния контрола, а косвенная, реализованная через отправку сообщений этому окну. Например, Expand, это вызов вида

```
UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(tv, tv.Handle), 
                NativeMethods.TVM_EXPAND, NativeMethods.TVE_EXPAND, Handle);
```

Само по себе состояние не доступно в виде управляемых объектов, а если и доступно (в виде `Nodes`) - то разработчики WinForms хранят его прежде всего для того, чтобы обеспечить трансляцию вызовов из вашего кода в WinApi.

Соответственно, насчет удобства сериализации они не заморачивалсь.

Вам стоит явно отделить данные от представления, и использовать привязку данных для синхронизации изменений.

К сожалению, у WinForms все достаточно плохо с привязкой иерархических данных, так что скорее всего вам придется дописать [свой binder](https://dotnetpuzzle.wordpress.com/2014/12/17/winforms-treeview-data-binding-part-2-of-2/). Возможно, проще будет написать тупую сериализацию ручную сериализацию коллекции `Nodes`.

Comment: _"у WinForms все достаточно плохо с привязкой иерархических данных"_ -- не так хорошо как в WPF, но в WinForms она тоже есть. например для редактирования разных уровней xml надо совсем немного кода. пример есть в ответе на вопрос [Как привязать контролы к иерархическим данным](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478616)

Comment: @Stack топикастер спрашивает про привязку иерархических данных к **одному** контролу. ваш пример привязывает неиерархические данные (просто три связанных таблицы) к разным контролам (просто стоящим рядом на форме раздельным DataGridView). Не понимаю, как пример для **раздельных контролов** и **неиерархического** датасорса показывает это самое "тоже есть". Можете нарисовать пример с одним TreeView и байндинга стандартными механизами (т.е. не ручного добавления нод?)

Comment: _"ваш пример привязывает неиерархические данные"_ -- посмотрите внимательно пример. XML - это иерархические данные. и контролы работают с учетом этой иерархии. Вы говорите, что _"для раздельных контролов"_, но это не так. просто создайте WinForms проект в Visual Studio и запустите пример из ответа.

Comment: @Stack то, что у вас в ответе - это Master-Details с тремя фиксированным уровнями. и тремя раздельными гридами - для первого, второго  и третьего уровней. Это не иерархический датабайндинг :)

Comment: @Stack попробуйте заменить в своем примере три раздельных грида на один TreeView. и добавить еще пару уровней в xml. посмотрим, взлетит или нет :)

Comment: _"это Master-Details с тремя фиксированным уровнями."_ -- сделайте больше уровней. никто не мешает. 
а _"иерархический датабайндинг"_ - это не Master-Details?

Comment: @Stack нет, это не Master-Details. Это байндинг вашего XML в TreeView - байндинг иерархических данных в *один* контрол. А не байндинг трех уровней иерархии (в виде плоских неиерархических таблиц) в три раздельных контрола.

Comment: @Stack - вот вам пример иерархического датабайндинга в WPF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035(v=vs.95).aspx. Попробуйте написать аналог на WinForms.  А вот то, что вы называете иерархическим байндингом - Creating *Master-Details Lists* with the Windows Forms DataGrid Control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984328(v=vs.71).aspx. Это две совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: _"попробуйте заменить в своем примере три раздельных грида на один TreeView."_ -- нельзя просто так что-то достать из одного контекста и поместить в другой. работать не будет. из фразы _"у WinForms все достаточно плохо"_ я так понял, что вообще у всех контролов плохо. но это не совсем так. если надо TreeView привзяать к данным то пример [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=7884)

Comment: @Stack оно не будет работать не из-за смены контекста, а из-за того, что там используется неиерархический биндинг к неиерархическим контролам. И он просто неприменим к TreeView. По вашей ссылке - обычное ручное перестроение дерева при смене данных (только встроенное в кастомный контрол дерева, а не в виде внешнего байндера, как по ссылке у меня в ответе). Проблема у топикастера все равно была не в байндинге, а в том, что он сами данные хранил только в TreeView - т.е. он вообще байндинг не использовал, и не имел прямого доступа к модели.

Comment: _"там используется неиерархический биндинг к неиерархическим контролам. И он просто неприменим к TreeView."_ -- его просто Microsoft в TreeView не реализовали. при необходимости ничего не мешает создать наследника и т.д. И привязаться прямо к тегам xml и атрибутам. _"обычное ручное перестроение дерева"_ -- вы точно мой пример смотрите? в моем примере три контрола. данные меняете в ячейках DataGridView, и автоматом получаете новый xml.

Comment: @Stack "обычное ручное перестроение дерева"  - это по ссылке на codeproject из вашего предыдущего сообщения. *"его просто Microsoft в TreeView не реализовали. при необходимости ничего не мешает создать наследника"* - ну да, я к этому и веду :) В WinForms нет готовой реализации для байндинга иерархических данных. Ничто не мешает создать наследника и написать свою собственную реализацию. Но в самих WinForms ее нет (== "все плохо"). Практически это и написано в последнем абзаце моего ответа (там точно есть слова "придется дописать"). Не понимаю в чем вы пытаеетсь меня убедить :)

Comment: @Stack ну ок. я могу переформулировать как "В WinForms с иерархическим байндингов все хорошо - встроенной поддержки нет и не будет, все родные механизмы байндинга рассчитаны на плоские структуры, и деревья они просто не понимают, но никто не мешает вам написать ее с нуля самостоятельно!". будет звучать оптимистично! :)

Comment: _"В WinForms нет готовой реализации для байндинга иерархических данных"_ -- иерархия может быть в виде xml, но для работы с данными в основном используются связанные таблицы. наверное вы знаете про sql и т.д. так вот в WinForms реализованы привязки к иерархиям в виде связанных таблиц. кстати, xml легко преобразуется в таблицы и обратно.

Comment: @Stack связанные таблицы - это неиерархические данные. иерархические данные - это одна таблица со связью сама на себя, например. Посмотрите пример из MSDN, чтобы ощутить разницу: [How to: Use a TreeView to Display Hierarchical Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035(v=vs.95).aspx) и попробуйте написать аналог для WinForms. От того, что вы назовете две таблицы "иерархией" - они иерархией не станут :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33519/discussion-between-pashapash-and-stack).

Answer (score 0):

У TreeNode есть свойство Text, которое отображается в контроле TreeView. Можно сохранить все значения TreeNode.Text в xml.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var f = new Form();
    var t = CreateTreeView();
    t.Parent = f;
    f.ShowDialog();
    Console.WriteLine(GetXml(t.Nodes));   // создать и вывести xml
}

static TreeView CreateTreeView() {
    var t = new TreeView() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    var n1 = t.Nodes.Add("n1");
    n1.Nodes.Add("n11");
    var n12 = n1.Nodes.Add("n12");
    n12.Nodes.Add("n121");
    t.ExpandAll();
    return t;
}

static string GetXml(TreeNodeCollection nodes, bool recursive=true) {
    var xe = new XElement("tree");
    foreach(var n in nodes.OfType<TreeNode>())
        ToXml(n, xe, recursive);
    return xe.ToString();
}
static void ToXml(TreeNode n, XElement trg, bool recursive=true) {
    var xe = new XElement("node", new XAttribute("text", n.Text));
    trg.Add(xe);
    if(recursive)
        foreach (var c in n.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>())
            ToXml(c, xe, recursive);
}
```

результат

```
<tree>
  <node text="n1">
    <node text="n11" />
    <node text="n12">
      <node text="n121" />
    </node>
  </node>
</tree>
```